# MyBatis: Getting affected rows number using java interface mapper

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mybatis

Reading MyBatis tutorial I understood that using session in order to execute query is old practice and it's much better to use java interface mapper. I mean that is a good practice :

```
mapper=session.getMapper(mapperClass);
mapper.updateFoo(boo);
```

I started using interface mappers and now I need to get the number of affected rows. All examples I've found are with `int number=session.update()`

My question how to get number of affected rows using mapper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just get the affected rows using java interface mapper in a similar way.

```
int number = mapper.updateFoo(boo);
```

And the java interface should be something like follows.

```
int updateFoo(Foo boo);
```

Comment: In your XML file, it should be specified as an `<update>` or `<delete>`.